# javascript textbox validation fires custom validator error regardless of value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to validate a textbox based on a dropdownlist, e.g. if ddl value is 'Day', textbox value cannot exceed 31. It seems that no matter what I enter triggers my custom validator error, what am I doing wrong, thanks:

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="uitxtCamLastVisitDur" runat="server" CssClass="tooltip" 
                         Width="65px" Enabled="False" ToolTip="Indicates a required spending on the member's last visit."></asp:TextBox> 
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="ccvLastVisitDuration" runat="server" 
                ClientValidationFunction="validateDurationType" 
                ControlToValidate="uitxtCamLastVisitDur"
                ErrorMessage="Duration input error"></asp:CustomValidator>

function validateDurationType(src, args) {

    if (document.getElementById('<%= uiddlCamLastVisitDurType.ClientID%>').selectedIndex == 1)
        if (parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= uitxtCamLastVisitDur.ClientID%>').value < 0) || (parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= uitxtCamLastVisitDur.ClientID%>').value > 31))) {
            args.IsValid = false;
            return;
     }
     if (document.getElementById('<%= uiddlCamLastVisitDurType.ClientID%>').selectedIndex == 2)
        if (parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= uitxtCamLastVisitDur.ClientID%>').value < 0) || (parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= uitxtCamLastVisitDur.ClientID%>').value > 12))) {
            args.IsValid = false;
            return;
     }  
  args.IsValid = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have javascript errors on your function. You are missing parenthesis on parseInt:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= uitxtCamLastVisitDur.ClientID%>').value < 0)
```

Should be

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= uitxtCamLastVisitDur.ClientID%>').value) < 0)
```

All of them have the same issue, by the way.